# How to solve boolean logic wiht Pyomo

Tags: python, linear-programming, finance, pyomo

I need to include a calculation in Pyomo optimization but I receive a message that it becomes boolean logic. I am using glpk which is suitable for linear programming. Is there an alternative to include this calculation in the optimization? Below is a very simplified example.

```
spread_min_150  =  0.01
spread_150_max  =  0.05

SPOT = 600
avg = 10
h = 730


def price(SPOT, POSITION, spread_min_150, spread_150_max):
    if SPOT < 150:
        spread_price  =  SPOT * (1 + spread_min_150) if POSITION >= 0 else SPOT * (1 - spread_min_150)
    else:
        spread_price  =  SPOT * (1 + spread_150_max) if POSITION >= 0 else SPOT * (1 - spread_150_max)
    return spread_price

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.a = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.b = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

mcp = avg * 730 - (model.a*730 + model.b*730)

B = mcp * price(SPOT, mcp, spread_min_150, spread_150_max)

model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=B, sense=pyo.minimize)

model.obj.pprint()

opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk') # ('glpk', executable='/usr/bin/glpsol')
result = opt.solve(model)
print(result)
model.display()
```

The error message is below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PyomoException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-c3d5ce23abb2> in <cell line: 22>()
     20 mcp = avg * 730 - (model.a*730 + model.b*730)
     21 
---> 22 B = mcp * price(SPOT, mcp, spread_min_150, spread_150_max)
     23 
     24 model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=B, sense=pyo.minimize)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyomo/core/expr/relational_expr.py in __bool__(self)
     46         if self.is_constant():
     47             return bool(self())
---> 48         raise PyomoException(
     49             """
     50 Cannot convert non-constant Pyomo expression (%s) to bool.

PyomoException: Cannot convert non-constant Pyomo expression (0  <=  7300 - (730*a + 730*b)) to bool.
This error is usually caused by using a Var, unit, or mutable Param in a
Boolean context such as an "if" statement, or when checking container
membership or equality. For example,
    >>> m.x = Var()
    >>> if m.x >= 1:
    ...     pass
and
    >>> m.y = Var()
    >>> if m.y in [m.x, m.y]:
    ...     pass
would both cause this exception.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual error message in addition to summarizing it according to your understanding.

Comment: This code has errors.  You are using both `model` and `modelo`.  What is `modelo`?  it is not defined

Comment: The question was adjusted for both comments.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing a few other typos, your code runs fine.  In your objective statement, you need to declare that `B` is an expression.  But even without that, it does not produce the error that you cite, so I think perhaps this isn't the exact code that produces the error you describe ???

Regardless, this works:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

spread_min_150  =  0.01
spread_150_max  =  0.05

SPOT = 600
POSITION = 10

def price(SPOT, POSITION, spread_min_150, spread_150_max):
    if SPOT < 150:
        spread_price  =  SPOT * (1 + spread_min_150) if POSITION >= 0 else SPOT * (1 - spread_min_150)
    else:
        spread_price  =  SPOT * (1 + spread_150_max) if POSITION >= 0 else SPOT * (1 - spread_150_max)
    return spread_price

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.a = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

B = model.a * price(SPOT, POSITION, spread_min_150, spread_150_max)

model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=B, sense=pyo.minimize)

model.obj.pprint()

opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk') # ('glpk', executable='/usr/bin/glpsol')
result = opt.solve(model)
print(result)
model.display()
```

Comment: You are right. The program is a simplification of what I am really using. It is too big to post here. Now I could reproduce the same error in the simplified version. Just reviewed the question with the mistake that is really happening.